# Rails: how to represent available view actions in a stateful model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a model that is stateful. In each state there are a selection of actions that the user might want to perform on an instance of the model. Currently I am translating the model state to actions that get represented in the view using a view helper.

Something like this... in the model:

```
Class Thing

  def state_is_A?
    state == 'A'
  end

end
```

In the helper:

```
def display_available_actions(thing)
  if thing.state_is_A?
    link_to <action1>
    link_to <action2>
  end
end
```

And in the view:

```
<%= display_available_actions(@thing) %>
```

I don't like the fact that the model state is translated into view actions in the helper. I would like this to be incorporated into the model. On the other hand, it doesn't seem healthy for the model and view to get so coupled.

Is there a Ruby or Rails idiom that suits this kind of situation better than my approach? Should each state be a separate model perhaps?

Comment: Your approach is quite good. I wouldn't be worrying of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm always using [aasm](http://github.com/rubyist/aasm) which gives you those `state_is_A?` methods automatically as well as `SomeModel.states` and information about the available transitions.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'm going to give aasm a try.

Comment: Thomas, is your link to the definitive AASM? In looking around the web for more info I came across many mentions of multiple AASM forks. Also, any documentation beyond the readme that you would suggest as a starting point?

Comment: for rails2 yes, in rails3 activesupport came with a statemachine but they've excluded it again. funny little bastards ;-)
documentation wise, the README is all there is, an rdoc should give you more from the internal API.